# Angular 2 new form, on submit redirecting to same page with form fields appended in URL as query params with new Router version

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I was updating my old running application to newer angular version. It was working good with older version.

On one of my page, I have used form, so when I updated `angular/forms` to `0.2.0` version with component router version `3.0.0-beta.1`. The issue I'm facing is when I tried to submit form, it redirects to same page and appending all the entered value in query parameter.

Here is [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AsY30IOOvMXXlFhploLa?p=preview) with Problem statement

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. You will get landed on "CRISIS CENTER" page, select any record from it.
2. Edit some text, and then click on submit button & check the URL in navigation bar.

> **Note**
>
> 1. I'm using template driven form(I don't think so this will make any difference).
> 2. Open Plunkr in Preview window(new tab where you can see running application URL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, but it wasn't happening on every route, which was frustrating to debug.

I ended up adding a `preventDefault` on the normal form `submit` and found out that there was an error on my page upon running through my `ngSubmit` method. Once I fixed that error, I was able to remove the `preventDefault` and it worked the way it's supposed to (without appending the query params).

html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" (submit)="preventDefault($event)">...</form>
```

ts

```
public preventDefault(event: Event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I like your idea, it would be nice to create a directive which will do preventDefault for us on form submit event.. but ideally it shouldn't happen